# Multiple Django sites in the same server with different databases

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm deploying the same Django project twice in a server with different settings and databases each one.

First one is a production project using **production.py** settings and **PostgreSQL** database
The second one is a test project using **development.py** settings and **Sqlite** database

Following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial, each one has a different socket, Gunicorn configuration, Nginx site enabled and different subdomain.

The problem is that when I'm trying to login into the test's project admin site I have to use the production credentials and see production data.

Which is the problem here?

Comment: Show us you config files, nginx conf files etc..

Comment: You should have two .sock files. Probably is an NGINX misconfiguration, is it possible you're binding two different urls to the same socket? Can you edit your question and share your NGINX configuration (removing sensitive data, if any)

Comment: It's all about Google Chrome caché...